# Solr cannot search for nutch crawled entries, despite fields being signed as indexed = true

Tags: indexing, solr, web-crawler, nutch

I'm running both a Nutch 1.16 crawler instance and a Solr version 8.3.0. I have been able to crawl for files on a local directory and, editing `nutch-site.xml`, extract some metadata from them (albeit not as much as I wished for) running `bin/crawl -s urls dircrawl 2 >& dircrawl.log`. The crawled data is then sent to Solr via `bin/nutch index dircrawl/crawldb/ -linkdb dircrawl/linkdb/ -dir dircrawl/segments/ -filter -normalize`, where the entries are then stored and managed via their tags.

Now, running Solr Admin from the UI, I'm trying to search for the data. I made sure to sign as `indexed=true` all the entries I am interested in. HOWEVER, running any search other than for `*:*` returns zero results. I have tried all possible combinations of search fields, no dice either. I'll link to the description of my config files, first for solr then for nutch...

```
schema.xml (becomes managed-schema when running it, for some reason)

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema name="nutch-crawler-indexing-config" version="1.6">
  <uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>
  <fieldType name="_nest_path_" class="solr.NestPathField" omitTermFreqAndPositions="true" omitNorms="true" maxCharsForDocValues="-1" stored="false"/>
  <fieldType name="ancestor_path" class="solr.TextField">
    <analyzer type="index">
      <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
      <tokenizer class="solr.PathHierarchyTokenizerFactory" delimiter="/"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
  (all fieldTypes are the default ones)
  <fieldType name="text_cjk" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer>
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.CJKWidthFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.CJKBigramFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
  <fieldType name="text_general_rev" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer type="index">
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="stopwords.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.ReversedWildcardFilterFactory" maxPosQuestion="2" maxFractionAsterisk="0.33" maxPosAsterisk="3" withOriginal="true"/>
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.SynonymGraphFilterFactory" expand="true" ignoreCase="true" synonyms="synonyms.txt"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="stopwords.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
  <fieldType name="text_gl" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer>
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="lang/stopwords_gl.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.GalicianStemFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
  <fieldType name="text_hi" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer>
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.IndicNormalizationFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.HindiNormalizationFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="lang/stopwords_hi.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.HindiStemFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
  <fieldType name="text_hu" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer>
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" format="snowball" words="lang/stopwords_hu.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="Hungarian"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
  <fieldType name="text_hy" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer>
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="lang/stopwords_hy.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="Armenian"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
  <fieldType name="text_id" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer>
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="lang/stopwords_id.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.IndonesianStemFilterFactory" stemDerivational="true"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
  <fieldType name="text_it" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer>
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.ElisionFilterFactory" articles="lang/contractions_it.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" format="snowball" words="lang/stopwords_it.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.ItalianLightStemFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
  <fieldType name="text_ja" class="solr.TextField" autoGeneratePhraseQueries="false" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer>
      <tokenizer class="solr.JapaneseTokenizerFactory" mode="search"/>
      <filter class="solr.JapaneseBaseFormFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.JapanesePartOfSpeechStopFilterFactory" tags="lang/stoptags_ja.txt"/>
      <filter class="solr.CJKWidthFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="lang/stopwords_ja.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.JapaneseKatakanaStemFilterFactory" minimumLength="4"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
  <fieldType name="text_ko" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer>
      <tokenizer class="solr.KoreanTokenizerFactory" outputUnknownUnigrams="false" decompoundMode="discard"/>
      <filter class="solr.KoreanPartOfSpeechStopFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.KoreanReadingFormFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
  <fieldType name="text_lv" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer>
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="lang/stopwords_lv.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.LatvianStemFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
  <fieldType name="text_nl" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer>
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" format="snowball" words="lang/stopwords_nl.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.StemmerOverrideFilterFactory" dictionary="lang/stemdict_nl.txt" ignoreCase="false"/>
      <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="Dutch"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
  <fieldType name="text_no" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer>
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" format="snowball" words="lang/stopwords_no.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="Norwegian"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
  <fieldType name="text_pt" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer>
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" format="snowball" words="lang/stopwords_pt.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.PortugueseLightStemFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
  <fieldType name="text_ro" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer>
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="lang/stopwords_ro.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="Romanian"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
  <fieldType name="text_ru" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer>
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" format="snowball" words="lang/stopwords_ru.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="Russian"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
  <fieldType name="text_sv" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer>
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" format="snowball" words="lang/stopwords_sv.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="Swedish"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
  <fieldType name="text_th" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer>
      <tokenizer class="solr.ThaiTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="lang/stopwords_th.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
  <fieldType name="text_tr" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer>
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.TurkishLowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="lang/stopwords_tr.txt" ignoreCase="false"/>
      <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="Turkish"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
  <fieldType name="text_ws" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer>
      <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
  <field name="_nest_path_" type="_nest_path_"/>
  <field name="_root_" type="string" docValues="false" indexed="true" stored="false"/>
  <field name="_text_" type="text_general" multiValued="true" indexed="true" stored="false"/>
  <field name="_version_" type="plong" indexed="false" stored="false"/>
  <field name="boost" type="pdoubles"/>
  <field name="content" type="text_general"/>
  <field name="digest" type="text_general"/>
  <field name="id" type="string" multiValued="false" indexed="true" required="true" stored="true"/>
  <field name="metatag.author" type="text_general" indexed="true"/>
  <field name="metatag.channels" type="plongs"/>
  <field name="metatag.creator" type="text_general" indexed="true"/>
  <field name="metatag.samplerate" type="plongs"/>
  <field name="metatag.version" type="text_general"/>
  <field name="title" type="text_general" indexed="true"/>
  <field name="tstamp" type="pdates"/>
  <field name="url" type="text_general" stored="true"/>
  <dynamicField name="*_txt_en_split_tight" type="text_en_splitting_tight" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <dynamicField name="*_descendent_path" type="descendent_path" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <dynamicField name="*_ancestor_path" type="ancestor_path" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <dynamicField name="*_txt_en_split" type="text_en_splitting" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <dynamicField name="*_txt_sort" type="text_gen_sort" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <dynamicField name="ignored_*" type="ignored"/>
  <dynamicField name="*_txt_rev" type="text_general_rev" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <dynamicField name="*_phon_en" type="phonetic_en" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <dynamicField name="*_s_lower" type="lowercase" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <dynamicField name="*_txt_cjk" type="text_cjk" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <dynamicField name="random_*" type="random"/>
  <dynamicField name="*_t_sort" type="text_gen_sort" multiValued="false" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <dynamicField name="*_txt_en" type="text_en" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <dynamicField name="*_txt_ar" type="text_ar" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <dynamicField name="*_txt_bg" type="text_bg" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <dynamicField name="*_txt_ca" type="text_ca" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <dynamicField name="*_txt_cz" type="text_cz" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <dynamicField name="*_txt_da" type="text_da" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <dynamicField name="*_txt_de" type="text_de" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <dynamicField name="*_txt_el" type="text_el" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <dynamicField name="*_txt_es" type="text_es" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <dynamicField name="*_txt_et" type="text_et" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <dynamicField name="*_txt_eu" type="text_eu" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <dynamicField name="*_txt_fa" type="text_fa" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <dynamicField name="*_txt_fi" type="text_fi" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <dynamicField name="*_txt_fr" type="text_fr" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <dynamicField name="*_txt_ga" type="text_ga" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <dynamicField name="*_txt_gl" type="text_gl" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <dynamicField name="*_txt_hi" type="text_hi" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <dynamicField name="*_txt_hu" type="text_hu" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <dynamicField name="*_txt_hy" type="text_hy" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <dynamicField name="*_txt_id" type="text_id" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <dynamicField name="*_txt_it" type="text_it" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <dynamicField name="*_txt_ja" type="text_ja" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <dynamicField name="*_txt_ko" type="text_ko" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <dynamicField name="*_txt_lv" type="text_lv" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <dynamicField name="*_txt_nl" type="text_nl" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <dynamicField name="*_txt_no" type="text_no" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <dynamicField name="*_txt_pt" type="text_pt" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <dynamicField name="*_txt_ro" type="text_ro" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <dynamicField name="*_txt_ru" type="text_ru" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <dynamicField name="*_txt_sv" type="text_sv" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <dynamicField name="*_txt_th" type="text_th" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <dynamicField name="*_txt_tr" type="text_tr" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <dynamicField name="*_point" type="point" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <dynamicField name="*_srpt" type="location_rpt" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <dynamicField name="attr_*" type="text_general" multiValued="true" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <dynamicField name="*_txt" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <dynamicField name="*_str" type="strings" docValues="true" indexed="false" stored="false" useDocValuesAsStored="false"/>
  <dynamicField name="*_dts" type="pdate" multiValued="true" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <dynamicField name="*_dpf" type="delimited_payloads_float" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <dynamicField name="*_dpi" type="delimited_payloads_int" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <dynamicField name="*_dps" type="delimited_payloads_string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <dynamicField name="*_is" type="pints" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <dynamicField name="*_ss" type="strings" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <dynamicField name="*_ls" type="plongs" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <dynamicField name="*_bs" type="booleans" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <dynamicField name="*_fs" type="pfloats" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <dynamicField name="*_ds" type="pdoubles" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <dynamicField name="*_dt" type="pdate" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <dynamicField name="*_ws" type="text_ws" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <dynamicField name="*_i" type="pint" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <dynamicField name="*_s" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <dynamicField name="*_l" type="plong" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <dynamicField name="*_t" type="text_general" multiValued="false" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <dynamicField name="*_b" type="boolean" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <dynamicField name="*_f" type="pfloat" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <dynamicField name="*_d" type="pdouble" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <dynamicField name="*_p" type="location" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <copyField source="digest" dest="digest_str" maxChars="256"/>
  <copyField source="title" dest="title_str" maxChars="256"/>
  <copyField source="url" dest="url_str" maxChars="256"/>
  <copyField source="content" dest="content_str" maxChars="256"/>
  <copyField source="metatag.author" dest="metatag.author_str" maxChars="256"/>
  <copyField source="metatag.version" dest="metatag.version_str" maxChars="256"/>
  <copyField source="metatag.creator" dest="metatag.creator_str" maxChars="256"/>
</schema>
```

then
    nutch-site.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>


<configuration>
<property>
 <name>http.agent.name</name>
 <value>NutchSpiderTest</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>http.robots.agents</name>
  <value>NutchSpiderTest,*</value>
  <description>...
  </description>
</property>

<property>
  <name>plugin.includes</name>
  <value>protocol-file|urlfilter-regex|parse-(html|tika|metatags|text)|index-(basic|anchor|metadata)|indexer-solr|scoring-opic|urlnormalizer-(pass|regex|basic)</value>
  <description>...
  </description>
</property>

<property>
 <name>file.content.limit</name>
 <value>-1</value>
 <description> Needed to stop buffer overflow errors - Unable to read.....</description>
</property>

<property>
  <name>file.crawl.parent</name>
  <value>false</value>
  <description>The crawler is not restricted to the directories that you specified in the
    Urls file but it is jumping into the parent directories as well. For your own crawlings you can
    change this behavior (set to false) the way that only directories beneath the directories that you specify get
    crawled.</description>
</property>


<property>
    <name>parser.skip.truncated</name>
    <value>false</value>
    <description>Boolean value for whether we should skip parsing for truncated documents. By default this
        property is activated due to extremely high levels of CPU which parsing can sometimes take.
    </description>
</property>
<!--
  <value>protocol-file|protocol-http|protocol-httpclient|urlfilter-(regex|validator)|parse-(html|tika|text)|index-(basic|anchor)|indexer-solr|scoring-opic|urlnormalizer-(pass|regex|basic)|index-more</value>
-->

<!-- Used only if plugin parse-metatags is enabled. -->
<property>
<name>metatags.names</name>
<value>*</value>
<description> ...
</description>
</property>

<property>
  <name>index.parse.md</name>
  <value>metatag.description,metatag.keywords,metatag.author,metatag.channels,metatag.content_encoding,metatag.content_type,metatag.creator,metatag.dc_creator,metatag.dc_title,metatag.id,metatag.meta_author,metatag.samplerate,metatag.stream_content_type,metatag.stream_name,metatag.stream_size,metatag.stream_source_info,metatag.title,metatag.version,metatag.x_parsed_by,metatag.xmpdm_album,metatag.album,metatag.xmpdm_albumartist,metatag.albumartist,metatag.xmpdm_artist,metatag.artist,metatag.xmpdm_audiochanneltype,metatag.audiochanneltype,metatag.xmpdm_audiocompressor,metatag.audiocompressor,metatag.xmpdm_audiosamplerate,metatag.audiosamplerate,metatag.xmpdm_composer,metatag.composer,metatag.xmpdm_discnumber,metatag.discnumber,metatag.xmpdm_duration,metatag.duration,metatag.xmpdm_genre,metatag.genre,metatag.xmpdm_releasedate,metatag.releasedate,metatag.xmpdm_tracknumber,metatag.tracknumber,metatag.copyright,author,Genre</value>
  <description>
  Comma-separated list of keys to be taken from the parse metadata to generate fields.
  Can be used e.g. for 'description' or 'keywords' provided that these values are generated
  by a parser (see parse-metatags plugin)
  </description>
</property>

</configuration>
```

Results of running a query for "*:*":

```
{
  "responseHeader":{
    ...,
    "params":{
      "q":"*:*",
      "_":"..."}},
  "response":{"numFound":24,"start":0,"docs":[
      {...
```

Response of running any other kind of query:

```
{
  "responseHeader":{
    ...
    "params":{
      "q":"Bumblebee",
      "_":"..."}},
  "response":{"numFound":0,"start":0,"docs":[]
  }}
```

Additionally, the data I'm trying to index is various .mp3 files from the Free Music Archive.

edit: the files I'm trying to search for look like this:

```
  {
        "metatag.author":["A Kombi",
          "A Kombi"],
        "metatag.samplerate":[44100,
          44100],
        "title":["Plight Of The Bumblebee"],
        "url":["file:/c:/Users/.../fma/fma_small/009/009476.mp3"],
        "content":["Plight Of The Bumblebee\nPlight Of The Bumblebee\nA Kombi\nMusic to Drive By, track 2\n2004-09-14T00:00:00\nField Recordings\n30014.912\n"],
        "metatag.creator":["A Kombi",
          "A Kombi"],
        "tstamp":["2020-04-02T15:26:29.507Z"],
        "digest":["ddd4ab2288c5799a5646592e1a63437f"],
        "boost":[0.20851442],
        "id":"file:/c:/Users/.../fma/fma_small/009/009476.mp3",
        "metatag.version":["MPEG 3 Layer III Version 1",
          "MPEG 3 Layer III Version 1"],
        "metatag.channels":[2,
          2],
        "_version_":1662875102548590596}
```

Comment: What document do you expect to get returned when just searching for `bumblebee`? You should usually provide a field name when using the Lucene query parser, i.e. `fieldname:bumblebee`. If you want to use plain text searches, append `defType=edismax&qf=fieldname_to_search_in` to your query to use the edismax query parser.

Comment: I am trying to retrieve metadata descriptions for mp3 files indexed after a nutch crawl. I've updated the question to include how the file looks like. I had already sent a POST command to solr to change 'title' into being indexed as well. I made sure that the field is updated in its entirety (I know POSTing to solr replaces the entire field), but it still won't let me search for anything that isn't "every document in the collection".

Comment: But if you're not using `qf` with `edismax`, you'll want to prefix with the field name. Have you tried that? i.e. `title:bumblebee`?

Comment: tried `http://localhost:8983/solr/nutchcoll/select?defType=edismax&fl=title&q=Bumblebee&stopwords=true` with zero results, then `http://localhost:8983/solr/nutchcoll/select?defType=edismax&qf=Bumblebee&stopwords=true` and `http://localhost:8983/solr/nutchcoll/select?defType=edismax&fl=title&qf=Bumblebee&stopwords=true` both with zero results. It should not be a problem of the solr installation because I have other collections and I can search just fine. I should mention, I'm performing these tasks from the admin UI.

Comment: `qf` is the _field_ you want to query. So in the first example you'll have to add `qf=title` to search in the title field. In the two other examples you're trying to search a field named `Bumblebee` - with no query. `qf` stands for "query fields" - i.e. which fields to query.

Comment: In Solr 8.3.0, at least as far as my knowledge goes, the fields are set with `fl`, in fact when I put "title" in there and look for all items, I get a list of all the item fields. But adding anything but *:* to the `q` fields returns zero documents. I tried what you said with `http://localhost:8983/solr/nutchcoll/select?defType=edismax&q=Bumblebee &qf=title&stopwords=true` and it worked. However, other collections that I have already created do not have this problem and will return items even just by inputting keywords in `q`. Why exactly is that?

Comment: No, `fl` is used to _set the fields returned in the response_ - not _which fields are being searched_. The reason is probably that there is a rule to copy everything into a common field in the background, which in the default schema is `_text_`. This field is then configured as the default search field for the lucene query parser as well - by default. But when you've used a different schema, those settings from default schema is no longer present.

Comment: Oh I see, sorry about it, it's my mistake. I do not understand though, did you mean to say that the copyfield rule for _text_ is probably what was going on for the other collections (where I can just put whatever in `q` and it would return some results) or are you talking about the `nutchcoll` collection? In addition to that, the other collections allow for partial matching, but it does not seem to be the case with this one, is there a way to do so? I mean, I could just do it by prefixing or suffixing *, but still... Thanks a lot, anyhow.

Comment: Partial matching will depend on the field type for the field you're querying. If it's `text_general`, only matches against words will be returned. If it's `text_ngram` or any of the other default types with ngrams (if you're using a default schema - these things are defined in the schema for each use case), you'll get partial hits as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set which field you're expecting to search against - unless you [have a default search field configured](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_5/the-standard-query-parser.html#standard-query-parser-parameters). In older versions of schema.xml this can be configured for the schema, but the recommended method is to configure it in the query itself.

However, to support free text search, it's far better to use the `edismax` query parser by supplying `defType=edismax` and then setting which fields you want to search through the `qf` (query fields) parameter.

```
q=Bumblebee&qf=title&defType=edismax
```

.. will search for Bumblebee in the `title` field. You can also give multiple field names to `qf`, and also adjust the weights given to each:

```
qf=title^10 content
```

.. which will search in both `title` and `content`, and give ten times more weight to any hits in the `title` field compared to a hit in the `content` field.

The `fl` (field list) parameter adjusts which fields are being returned in the response, which is useful if you only need a small subset of the available fields (such as just the id) to avoid a larger response and having to load all the field values from disk for each document returned.